# Why must I declare an exception if I know it will never be thrown?

Tags: java, exception

Suppose I have a function that declares an exception for a certain input, and I call it with input which is guaranteed to not throw an exception. The compiler forces me to declare or catch the exception for the second function even though I know for certain that it shan't be thrown. Is there any way to avoid declaring it? If there isn't, why isn't there? If the answer to that is because it's a bad idea, why is it a bad idea?

```java
public class Foo {
    private int n;

    public Foo(int n) throws NegativeNumberException {
        if (n < 0) throw new NegativeNumberException;
        this.n = n;
    }

    public Foo square() { // Why must I declare throws NegativeNumberException
        return new Foo(n*n);
    }
}
```

Edit: I know I can make my exception not require declarations at all, but I do want it to be declared in general, just not in the case where I know it won't be thrown.

Comment: Is the fact that `Foo` will throw an exception when `n < 0` a part of the _contract_, or an _implementation detail_? This is an important piece of information that will determine what you should do here.

Comment: How does the compiler know that you will not call `new Foo(-19)` ?

Comment: Also, `n*n` is not always positive. Consider the case when it overflows.

Comment: @Sweeper fair enough, but that was just a MWE. Consider for example a method which returns a copy of itself

Comment: @Sweeper It is not part of the contract, I know, but conceptually it could be. If I could make that part of the contract then it would not be an issue, but unfortunately I cannot

Comment: You can’t because the language is designed that way. If you don’t want to force users to catch or rethrow, don’t declare exceptions. Note that C# and Kotlin, both newer languages, got rid of checked exceptions because they were widely regarded as a design mistake in retrospect. If you know an exception won’t be thrown, wrap in try/catch.

Comment: I agree with Tenfour04. If it's "conceptually" the contract, then the exception shouldn't be checked. You seem to have a wrong idea about what checked exceptions are about.

Comment: `new Foo(50000).square()` → `NegativeNumberException` *Oops!* It can be negative, because 50000 * 50000 overflows and becomes -1794967296. This is the overflow mentioned by [Sweeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66648166/why-must-i-declare-an-exception-if-i-know-it-will-never-be-thrown#comment117817230_66648166).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java checked exceptions are designed to offer hard guarantees. A 'throws' clause for a checked exception is an interface contract.

You're apparently asking how your code can promise it won't invalidate the hard guarantee.

Having such a feature in the language seems to be at odds with having checked exceptions in the first place.

It seems similar to me to data type issues. Consider

```
  void func(int n) {
       char c = int n;
  }
```

The compiler objects to the narrowing. "But I promise n < 128".  Sorry, not good enough.  You need to write the approved way of handling it, namely a cast expression.  Similarly, for checked exceptions, you need to write an approved way of handling it, for example a catch-clause.

Answer (score 1):

So, in your square() (caller function) , you are calling Foo(int) (called function) , and  Foo(int) might throw an exception. The point of throwing an exception from a function is to handle it in the caller function, otherwise the exception doesn't get handled and your app probably crashes.
Therefore, in such cases you have 2 options:

1- Handle the thrown exception in the caller function by using try - catch

2- Again, throw this exception from the caller function, so now the responsibility of handling this thrown error is on the function which called your square() function.

Anyway, It's wrong to declare a function with the possiblity of throwing exception but not handling this potential exception in your caller functions.

Answer (score 1):

The type system doesn't understand that n*n is guaranteed to be positive.

You might be able to model what you know about the properties of your domain in the type system to make your code safer, see the toy example below.

```
class Number {
    int n;
    public Number(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }
    Number add(Number a) {
        return new Number(n + a.n);
    }

    static PositiveNumber square(Number n) {
        return new PositiveNumber(n.n * n.n);
    }
}

class PositiveNumber extends Number {

    public PositiveNumber(int n) {
        super(n);
    }
    
    PositiveNumber add(PositiveNumber a) {
        return new PositiveNumber(a.n + n);
    }
}

public class Main
{
    static void foo(PositiveNumber n) {
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        PositiveNumber a = new PositiveNumber(1);
        PositiveNumber b = new PositiveNumber(2);
        Number c = new Number(-1);
        foo(a.add(b)); // ok, adding two positive numbers is always positive
        foo(a.add(c)); // fails to type check
        foo(Number.square(c)); // ok, squaring a number is always positive
    }
}
```